# Calculating DBPedia resources with the most predicates

Tags: rdf, sparql, dbpedia

I thought it would be interesting to ask DBPedia which of its resources are the most predicate-rich.

I tried running the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?s (count(?p) AS ?info)
WHERE {
  ?s ?p ?o .
}
GROUP BY ?s ?p
ORDER BY desc(?info)
LIMIT 50
```

and it timed out, so I can't verify whether or not it was the right query.

So, I'm left with the following two questions:

1. is this the correct way to ask this question?
2. is the query too computationally expensive to run (even on smaller datasets? DBP is 2.46b triples)?

Comment: If you `group by ?s ?p`, then you're asking which subject and predicate pair has the most values.  If you want to know which are the subject of the most triples, you just want to `group by ?s`.  I think you'll still be likely to time out, though, because the query has to look at _every_ triple in the data, organize them by subject, and count.  That's _a lot_ of work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The right way to ask this

Suppose you've got data like this:

```
@prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/22391927/1281433/> .

:a :p 1, 2, 3 ;
   :q 4, 5 .

:b :p 1, 2 ;
   :q 3, 4 ;
   :r 5, 6 .

:c :p 1 ;
   :q 2 ;
   :r 3 .
```

Then you can ask how many triples each resource is the subject of with a query like this:

```
prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/22391927/1281433/>

select ?s (count(*) as ?n) where {
  ?s ?p ?o
}
group by ?s
order by desc(?n)
```

```
----------
| s  | n |
==========
| :b | 6 |
| :a | 5 |
| :c | 3 |
----------
```

Notice that you only want to `group by ?s` if you're interested in how many triples each resource is the subject of.  In you original query, where you `group by ?s ?p`, you're going to sorting (subject,predicate) pairs by how many values they have.  E.g.,

```
prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/22391927/1281433/>

select ?s ?p (count(*) as ?n) where {
  ?s ?p ?o
}
group by ?s ?p
order by desc(?n)
```

```
---------------
| s  | p  | n |
===============
| :a | :p | 3 |
| :b | :p | 2 |
| :a | :q | 2 |
| :b | :q | 2 |
| :b | :r | 2 |
| :c | :p | 1 |
| :c | :q | 1 |
| :c | :r | 1 |
---------------
```

### Doing this for DBpedia

I don't expect that you'll be able to run a query like this on DBpedia.  It requires touching every triple in the data, and then ordering the resources by how many triples they're the subject of.  That sounds like a lot of work.  You might be able to download the data, load it into a local endpoint and run the query, and so avoid the timeout, but I wouldn't be surprised if it still takes a while.